# Importing a library perl script using "require" from remote server

Tags: perl, module

I have a library perl script called `/root/kart/test.pl` and this library script is getting imported as part of `main.pl` script.

**sample contents of `main.pl`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if(-f "/root/kart/test.pl" )
{
       require "/root/kart/test.pl";
}
our @array1;
our @array2;
```

**sample contents of `test.pl`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
our @array1=qw(one two three);
our @array2=qw(abc xyz);
.
.
1;
```

Before, the library perl script `/root/kart/test.pl` was available locally and `main.pl` was working fine. Now this script will be available only on remote node but not locally.

How to import a perl script using "require" from remote server in perl

Comment: Is `test.pl` a module (which would normally have `.pm` extension), with a collection of subroutines etc, or really an executable script?

Comment: @zdim its not a module, just a script which contains only arrays and variables with some predefined values.

Comment: `How to import a perl script using "require" from remote server in perl?` What error message do you get when importing the script from the server?

Comment: @kart1657  If that script doesn't really _do_ anything, can you not make it into a simple module? It'll make everything far better.  You will then still need to get the file from that remote host to where you run, but then you'll be dealing with a normal module that can be `use`d (or `require`d if you acquire it at run time from the script that uses it).

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a place where you can store configuration data for your scripts. Have you tried looking at JSON objects? The syntax is very similar to Perl arrayrefs and hashrefs, and they're easy to load into Perl (See [JSON on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) ). JSON was made to send to/from a server using HTTP requests and you can store the data in a text file or using a dedicated service like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can't successfully `require` anything that does not exist on the local machine, either in memory or as a file. So your question will revolve on how to get read access on the remote machine and how to copy the data in the test.pl file onto your machine.

There are some modules like [The::Net](https://metacpan.org/pod/The::Net) or [lazy](https://metacpan.org/pod/lazy) , which automate the download, installation and then local use of code for you, but as your situation is special to you, you will have to find the way yourself how to copy the data in `test.pl` to your local machine and then `eval` it.

Maybe mounting the remote file system is the easiest approach.

Comment: Just wanted to add that one of the reasons you can't remotely reference a module is because namespaces in Perl are directly tied to the file path. Perl uses a special variable called `@INC` that stores the directories Perl is allowed to look in for modules. So if you have `use Foo::Bar;` in the script and one of the paths in @INC is '/usr/share/perl', Perl will literally look for "/usr/share/perl/Foo/Bar.pm". If the module/library/script path can't be extrapolated from @INC then you need to tell Perl where to look, such as `use lib` or [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html).